# PHP + MySQL - Sorting Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I have a table with a column which can contain: "kldr", "bgg" or an integer.

Now i want a query with the result in the following order:

```
 1. kldr 
 2. kldr 
 3. bgg 
 4. bgg 
 5. 1  
 6. 2 
 7. 3
 8. etc.
```

Can anyone help me out? My current query is obvious not working.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE column_x='$value_x' 
ORDER BY column_y LIKE '%kldr%' ASC, LIKE '%bgg%' ASC, floor ASC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE column_x='$value_x' 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN column_y LIKE '%kldr%' THEN 1
              WHEN column_y LIKE '%bgg%' THEN 2
              ELSE column_y + 2
         END
```

Comment: Ah thanks. 'THEN' sets only the order position as i understand?

Comment: @RamonBakker `THEN` determines the number returned by the `CASE` expression.